# Create a menu pointing to #

Tags: routes, 7

Using [menu token](http://drupal.org/project/menu_token) I have created a menu as shown in figure

[image: snap]

I also have sub-menu items for this menu. Whenever the user clicks on this menu, the page is being refreshed (which is the obvious behavior), but I don't want any sort of action on the menu. In simple HTML we can do my simply using `href="#"`, but Drupal is not allowing to set the Path of the menu to `#`. Is there a way to do it?
I also tried [Menu attributes](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) to do it, but I seem to be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes drupal doesn't suppport # in menu_links, You might get some clues here - http://drupal.org/node/325533

Comment: +1 thanks for sharing the link. I found the solution :) All I needed to do is just change the menu path to `[node:url:absolute]#` (just appended `#` after the path). And it solved my problem :)